# Looking for tighter bound on symmetric PSD matrices products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let K and L be `symmetric PSD matrices` of size N*N, with all entries in [0,1]. Let `i` be any number in 1...N and K’, L’ be two new symmetric PSD matrices, each with only row `i` and column `i` different from K and L.

I would like to obtain an upper bound of the equation below: where `. ∗` is an element-wise multiply.

[image: equation]

Using simple triangular inequality and bounding the three square brackets respectively, 
I can bound the above with 12N − 13. 
However, this is extremely loose.
Empirical experiments show that the constant coefficient should be much lower, probably closer to 1N.

Can you suggest any linear algebra properties connecting the equation's parts - which may help me get a tighter bound?

Comment: Do you mean you want to find an upper bound of $$\left|\sum_{i,j}(K’\circ L’)_{ij}-\sum_{i,j}(K\circ L)_{ij}\right|
-\frac2N\left|\sum_{i,j}(K’L’)_{ij}-\sum_{i,j}(KL)_{ij}\right|
+\frac1{N^2}\left|\sum_{i,j}(K’)_{ij}\sum_{i,j}(L’)_{ij}-\sum_{i,j}(K)_{ij} \sum_{i,j}(L)_{ij}\right|?$$And what do you mean by $1N$? Is it a typo? What about $12N-13$?